# Sort namespaces by length

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Does anybody know about possibility sorting of the usings directives by length with resharper ?

before

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

after

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: I am also searching for this .... only possibility could be creating a plugin for VS, which does exactly this

Comment: any idea about how to do it without resharper?

Comment: Does [Rearrange Code Elements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Moving_Code_Elements.html#how-it-works) didn't do it? Note: i haven't use Resharper.

Comment: BTW: Is there any reason (aside from the aestetic one) to change the order of namespaces?

Comment: There is an answer here https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206651685-How-can-one-reorganize-and-sort-code-using-Resharper-

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio you can use a Marketplace Tool like "[Using Directive Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=everfor88.UsingDirectiveFormatter)"

For ReSharper it's standard within the cleanup.
You find it in the ReSharper | Tools | [Cleanup Code command](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html)

Shortcut: `Ctrl+E, C`. If this shortcut does not work you can setup your cleanup options in ReSharper | Options - under the Code Editing group.